# Camel: How to return a valid SOAP response after processing a CXF request

Tags: soap, cxf, response, apache-camel, envelope

So, I have a route that exposes a Webservice Endpoint. After the request is received, I send some information to some queues and I would like to return a response to the original caller.
The response is an enumeration that can have 4 values `(OK,NULL,RPT,NOK)`.

I can get the response in soapUI, but it's not in a valid SOAP Envelope. This means that when the response is processed in Java or .Net an exception is thrown saying there is no valid Envelope namespace.

How do I guarantee that the response being sent is a SOAPMessage?

To generate my responde message I have this method:

```
public OnClientEventResponse process(Message message){
    if(message.getBody().toString().contains("OnClientEventResponse")){
        return (OnClientEventResponse) message.getBody();
    }
    OnClientEventResponse resp = new OnClientEventResponse();
    resp.setReturn(Response.OK);
    return resp;
}
```

In soapUi I get this:

```
<onClientEventResponse>
   <Response>OK</Response>
</onClientEventResponse>
```

but I needed something like this:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="blabla/soap/envelope">
<soap:Headers/>
<soap:Body>
    <onClientEventResponse>
       <Response>OK</Response>
    </onClientEventResponse>
<soap:Body>
<soap:Envelope>
```

My Webservice interface class is :

```
@WebService(name = "ClientEventNotifierEndpoint")
public interface ClientEventNotifierEndpoint {

@WebMethod(operationName = "onClientEvent", action = "urn:OnClientEvent")
@WebResult(name = "return")
public Response onClientEvent(@WebParam(name = "readerCode") String readerCode, @WebParam(name = "clientRfid") String clientRfid,
        @WebParam(name = "eventType") String eventType, @WebParam(name = "dateTime") Date dateTime);
```

}

Answer (score 4):

I am sure you are no longer waiting for this answer but since I have just finished to look for the same here's what you have to do:

```
package com.xxxxx.esb.invoice.processors;

import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;

import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.Processor;
import org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfPayload;
import org.apache.camel.converter.jaxp.XmlConverter;
import org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapHeader;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;

import com.xxxxx.esb.invoice_service_spec.ProcessFileResponse;

/**
 * @author pantinor
 * 
 * 
 * 
 */
public class SoapResponseProcessor implements Processor {
    private static final String ROOT_NODE = "processFileResponse";
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://www.xxxxx.com/Esb/invoice-service    -spec";
    private static final String OK = "OK";
    protected static final Logger LOG = Logger
            .getLogger(SoapResponseProcessor.class);

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        //lots a support classes to serialize my answer
        List<Source> outElements = new ArrayList<Source>();
        XmlConverter converter = new XmlConverter();
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext
                .newInstance(ProcessFileResponse.class);
        Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();

        //build my business answer
        ProcessFileResponse result = new ProcessFileResponse();
        result.setReturn(OK);

        //serialize the answer

        //the following is required since the JAXB annotated class does not include     the XMLRoot annotation
        m.marshal(new JAXBElement<ProcessFileResponse>(new QName(NAMESPACE,
                ROOT_NODE), ProcessFileResponse.class, result), writer);

        Document outDocument = converter.toDOMDocument(writer.toString());
        outElements.add(new DOMSource(outDocument.getDocumentElement()));

        //use camel class cxf class to produce a payload that the cxf component can     consume for the answer
        CxfPayload<SoapHeader> responsePayload = new CxfPayload<SoapHeader>(
                null, outElements, null);

        //write the anwer
        exchange.getIn().setBody(responsePayload);


    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, indeed I no longer needed this but I'll try it when I get home and will get back to you. If it works I'll select it as the answer. Thanks for sharing.
The way I solved it back then was to add the Envelope myself, pretty crude but did the trick for the time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it works for camel, but try to add this annotation to your interface.

```
@WebService(name = "ClientEventNotifierEndpoint")
@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.RPC)
```

public interface ClientEventNotifierEndpoint {